# HTML Select Option Only Passing First Value To PHP

Tags: php, html, html-select

I have a program that I'm writing that is using a `<select>` in HTML. When I submit the form, and execute the PHP script, I'm using a `$_POST` to grab the selected option from the HTML page. However, it is only passing a "1" every time. I've tried selecting different values, but it is always selecting 1. Here's the code:

HTML:

```
<form id="form_22942" class="appnitro" method="post" action="../process/process.php">
  <div class="form_description"></div>
  </li>
  <li class="section_break">
    <h3>Deployment Constraints</h3>
    <p></p>
  </li>
  <li id="li_11">
    <label class="description" for="element_11">Corporate Policies and Procedures: </label>
    <div>
      <select class="element select medium" id="element_11" name="element_11"> 
        <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
        <option value="1" >Flexible</option>
        <option value="2" >Fixed</option>
      </select>
    </div>
</form>
```

PHP (process.php):

```
$corp_policy = $_POST['element_11'];
$entityname2 = "corp_policy";

if ($corp_policy = '1') {
    echo "<center>Corporate policies and procedures are flexible.<center>";
    $corp_policy_text = "Flexible";
}
else if ($corp_policy = '2') {
    echo "<center>Corporate policies and procedures are fixed.<center>";
    $corp_policy_text = "Fixed";
}
```

Comment: In addition to the fact that you're **assigning** to the variable `$corp_policy` rather than comparing, you also have some invalid HTML. You have a closing `</li>` with no opening tag just below `.form_description`, and also are missing the closing `</div>` for `.form_description` (just before `</form>`) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using these: (`==`)

```
if ($corp_policy == '1') {
    echo "<center>Corporate policies and procedures are flexible.<center>";
    $corp_policy_text = "Flexible";
}
else if ($corp_policy == '2') {
    echo "<center>Corporate policies and procedures are fixed.<center>";
    $corp_policy_text = "Fixed";
}
```

instead of these: (`=`)

```
if ($corp_policy = '1') {
    echo "<center>Corporate policies and procedures are flexible.<center>";
    $corp_policy_text = "Flexible";
}
else if ($corp_policy = '2') {
    echo "<center>Corporate policies and procedures are fixed.<center>";
    $corp_policy_text = "Fixed";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are assigning 1 to $corp_policy instead of comparing the two operands.

Use == or ===

Check the doc for more informations: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 0):

```
<select class="element select medium" id="element_11" name="element_11"> 
<option disabled selected > -- select an option -- </option>
        <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
        <option value="1" >Flexible</option>
        <option value="2" >Fixed</option>
 </select>
```

It works for me